# throw different message exception with message body

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-boot, exception, apache-commons

I am trying unzipping a zip file which might be empty no files and folder. It was throwing an **UnsupportedOperationException** therefore I was handling with **throw** keyword and then giving the message body to jsp page.

```
try {
    boolean upload=unzipUploadedFile(saveZip,folderName);

    if(upload)
            return ServiceResponse.createSuccessResponse();
            else
            return ServiceResponse.createFailureResponse("Files cannot be unzipped"); 

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ServiceResponse.createFailureResponse(e.getMessage());
        }

private boolean unzipUploadedFile(File saveZip, String folderName) throws Exception {
         //Open the file
        try(ZipFile file = new ZipFile(saveZip.getCanonicalPath()))
        {

        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        //Get file entries
        Path inputpath=fileSystem.getPath(file.getName());
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();

      //We will unzip files in this folder
            File directory=new File(zipFilePath.concat(folderName));

            if(!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
            }

        //Iterate over entries
        while (entries.hasMoreElements())
        {
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            String abc[]=entry.getName().split("/");

            //Else create the file
            if(!entry.isDirectory())
            {
                InputStream is = file.getInputStream(entry);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                String uncompressedFileName = zipFilePath +folderName+"/"+ abc[abc.length-1];
                Path uncompressedFilePath = fileSystem.getPath(uncompressedFileName);
                if(Files.notExists(uncompressedFilePath)) 
                Files.createFile(uncompressedFilePath);
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(uncompressedFileName);
                while (bis.available() > 0)
                {
                    fileOutput.write(bis.read());
                }
                fileOutput.close();
                System.out.println("Written :" + entry.getName());
                is.close();
                bis.close();
            }
        }
        file.close();
        Files.deleteIfExists(inputpath);
        fileSystem.close();

    }catch(UnsupportedOperationException e)
    {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Uploaded zip does not contain proper file or folder");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("File unizipping unsuccessful");
    }
    return true;
}
```

But if I add the zip with all files in it still it is giving me Uploaded zip does not contain proper file or folder at the UI end

Jsp page where I called the controller code

```
$
            .ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : baseUrl + url,
                data : data,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(dataset){
                    console.log(dataset.error);
                    document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
                    $('#reportError').modal('show');

                     document.getElementById('uploadError').innerHTML="<center>"+dataset.error+"</center>";
                     document.getElementById('error_title').innerHTML="Upload Failure";

                },

                error : function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Uploaded zip does not contain proper file or folder
        at com.tata.green.controller.GreenBackendServiceController.unzipUploadedF
ile(GreenBackendServiceController.java:580)
        at com.tata.green.controller.GreenBackendServiceController.uploadServerDe
tails(GreenBackendServiceController.java:509)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvok
e(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
```

Comment: Show the stack trace - i.e. where exactly the exception happens.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I have added the stack trace and exception is exactly at line where I using throw new UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @JozefChocholacek found anything?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I got the error while closing FileSystem it got fired....do you know why?

Comment: So the error is thrown at `fileSystem.close();`?

Comment: Actually, your `fileSystem` is a default one (created via `FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();` - and according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html), _file systems created by the default provider cannot be closed_, thus the `fileSystem.close();` line throws an exception. The message is misleading, indeed.